# For two stochastic process $x_t$, $y_t$, how can the cross-covariance function between $x_t$ and $y_t$ at lag k different from that at lag -k?

Tags: time-series, signal-processing

For two stochastic process $x_t$, $y_t$, how can the cross-covariance function between $x_t$ and $y_t$ at lag k different from that at lag -k?
For some reason, I can't scrape my head around this. Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the simple example $y_t=x_{t-1}$.  Then element 21 of the auto cross-covariance function at lag $k=1$ is
$$
\gamma_{21,1}=\operatorname{Cov}(x_{t-1},y_t)=\operatorname{Cov}(x_{t-t},x_{t-1})=\gamma_{11,0}
$$
whereas at lag $k=-1$ it is
$$
\gamma_{21,-1}=\operatorname{Cov}(x_{t+1},y_t)=\operatorname{Cov}(x_{t+1},x_{t-1})=\gamma_{11,2}.
$$
But note that 
\begin{align}
\gamma_{12,k}
  &=\operatorname{Cov}(x_{t-k},y_t)
\\&=\operatorname{Cov}(y_t,x_{t-k})
\\&=\operatorname{Cov}(y_{t+k},x_t)=\gamma_{21,-k}
\end{align}
so $\Gamma_k=\Gamma_{-k}^T$.

Comment: So in general, is there any scenario when the two autocovariance equal?

Comment: One example would be any vector ARMA process if all matrices are symmetric and with shared eigenvectors.  But that is essentially just a rotation of independent ARMA processes and so perhaps not so interesting.